# How to limit max connection allowed in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to limit the number of connection received by WSO2 ESB. Is there any property to be able to limit by properties (axis2, carbon, etc.)?

Comment: Can you explain the reason for limiting the number of connections received by the ESB? Is it because your backend cannot process a higher load?

Comment: I have two instances behind F5, and I want to avoid problems in higher load case. I saw in catalina-server.xml (tomcat settings) that there are some attributes like maxConnection, maxThread, etc. But I do not find a good documentations to fit these attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on the understanding gained from your comment. So, I assumed your backend has a limit of requests which can be processed which is less than what the ESB can accept.

There are two option:

1. Similar to catalina-server.xml for tomcat, there is pass-thru.properties file in the conf folder where you can tune certain parameters to suite the load you expect and also to match the capabilities of the VM you have hosted the ESB.
   https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Configuring+passthru-http.properties
2. One disadvantage of above option would be, some of your requests will not be accepted by the ESB if its too busy. To overcome that, you can use a queueing mechanism. i.e. You accept all the requests and store them in a message store (a queue). Then configure a message processor to retrieve those messages and process. Disadvantage of this option is, its difficult to cater a request response scenario.

As Bhathiya has mentioned, you can front your ESB with a WSO2 API Manager and throttle the requests too.

Answer (score 0):

Until ESB 4.8.1, it had [throttling feature](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Throttling). You also can use [Throttling Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Throttle+Mediator) in each service.

Another option is to front ESB by WSO2 API Manager which has complete [throttling support](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Working+with+Throttling).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that is to limit request at services level. We find any solution at server level. For example, limit maxConnector in Tomcat.